# Unable to fetch packages from deb.debian.org when building a Docker image for an Elixir Phoenix project

Tags: linux, docker, debian, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working on an Elixir Phoenix project which I recently got access to through GitHub. My objective is to set up and view the website locally using Docker. Here's a breakdown of what I've done:

**Setup:**

1. Installed Docker Desktop on my machine.
2. Cloned the project from GitHub.
3. The project uses a Dockerfile to define the environment.

**Issue:**
When I attempt to build the Docker image using docker-compose build, I encounter errors related to fetching packages from deb.debian.org.

Specifically, I'm seeing the following errors:

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-dashdash/node-dashdash_2.0.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:80: [IP: 146.75.22.132 80]
...
[repeat for other packages]
...
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-extsprintf/node-extsprintf_1.4.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:80: [IP: 146.75.22.132 80]

**Dockerfile Configuration:**
I initially had this configuration in my Dockerfile:
...
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update -y --fix-missing && apt-get install -y libvips-dev git npm 
&& apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*
...

Upon encountering the error, I was advised to switch the Debian mirrors, so I updated the Dockerfile to:
...
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main" > /etc/apt/sources.list && 
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && 
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && 
apt-get clean && apt-get update -y --fix-missing && apt-get install -y libvips-dev git npm && 
apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

...
However, I'm still encountering the same issue.

Here's my Dockerfile, https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kg1d5dgufy756zn6mj24q/Dockerfile?rlkey=e713c7mo3esocrphps0plgo9r&dl=0

Here's my docker-compose.yml, https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/oqsvnq8jstyqqyz070c6b/h?rlkey=xvimmk8dpzeofy5pj8v9aud7k&dl=0

Questions:

1. Is there a known issue with accessing deb.debian.org or is this potentially a problem with my Docker configuration?
2. Are there any recommended workarounds or alternative approaches I could take to successfully build the Docker image?
3. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The best way to build elixir images is to use [hexpm](https://hub.docker.com/r/hexpm/elixir). Without the Dockerfile, it's hard to say much more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, @AdamMillerchip. Here's my Dockerfile,  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kg1d5dgufy756zn6mj24q/Dockerfile?rlkey=e713c7mo3esocrphps0plgo9r&dl=0

Comment: I see. That is the Dockerfile [produced by `mix phx.gen.release --docker`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/main/priv/templates/phx.gen.release/Dockerfile.eex) and uses the hexpm images. It could be that the Debian image version `bullseye-20210902-slim` is no longer supported, maybe try [`bullseye-20230725-slim`](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) or a more recent version instead?

Comment: The URL http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-dashdash/node-dashdash_2.0.0-1_all.deb works fine so this is probably a network issue on your machine. You can debug with 'curl -v' to see why your machine could not fetch this file.

Comment: I appreciate your input, @bortzmeyer.